# Why is script in popup.js not working?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can someone help me, I'm building my first chrome extension and it's a popup with a button that's supposed to do something on click (just using alert now), but somehow whatever in my js file doesn't seem to be working. Styles also seem not to load.

**manifest:**

```json
{
  "name": "Toolbar",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "Toolbar",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "None",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="closeButton"> x<button/>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```javascript
function closePopup ()
{
    //window.close();
    alert("hello");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('closeButton').on("click", function (){
      closePopup();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to rightclick the popup, then `Inspect`, and look in the devtools console and the page DOM in Elements panel. 1. There's no such function in standard JS DOM as `.on()` (use addEventListener or onclick property), 2. `<button/>` is the wrong closing tag, should be `</button>`.

Comment: thanks for your response, I've updated the tags of course (it wasn't working with link either and I copy pasted the button all over incorrectly).

I've updated the last part to 

document.getElementById("closeButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    closePopup();
});

but no luck still.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at popup.js:27

Comment: but again the name of the button is correct. I'm confused.

Comment: got the same question, have u fixed it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<!--<script src="popup.js"></script> delete this-->
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button type="button" id="closeButton"> x<button/>
</div>
<!--add this--><script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**place the script after the object, where the eventlistener is placed on. I had the same problem and that fixed it**

Answer (score 0):

You've got to put the `<script src="popup.js"></script>` in the `<body>` instead of `<head>` tag. That worked for me.